Can't connect via SSH to OpenWrt after changing /etc/config/network

Setup

Mikrotik RouterBoard 750gr3

OS: OpenWrt 23.05.03


MacBook

Microtik: Port 1
IP: 10.13.1.201



Problem
Before a configuration change to /etc/config/network, SSH was possible, but after rebooting, I can't connect via SSH, and can't figure out what the problem is, trying multiple things.

ping doesn't work, saying host is down
Winbox is not finding the device

After installing OpenWrt, I customized /etc/config/network, changing it to:
config globals 'globals'
  option ula_prefix 'fdf7:aefc:1ed9::/48'

config interface  'loopback'
  option  ifname      'lo'
  option  proto       'static'
  option  ipaddr      '127.0.0.1'
  option  netmask     '255.0.0.0'

config switch
  option  name        'switch0'
  option  reset       '1'
  option  enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
  option  device      'switch0'
  option  vlan        '2'
  option  ports       '1 6t'
  option  vid         '2'

config switch_vlan
  option  device      'switch0'
  option  vlan        '3'
  option  ports       '2 6t'
  option  vid         '3'

config switch_vlan
  option  device      'switch0'
  option  vlan        '4'
  option  ports       '3 6t'
  option  vid         '4'

config switch_vlan
  option  device      'switch0'
  option  vlan        '5'
  option  ports       '4 6t'
  option  vid         '5'

config switch_vlan
  option  device      'switch0'
  option  vlan        '1'
  option  ports       '0 6t'
  option  vid         '1'

config interface 'mgmt'
  option  proto       'static'
  option  netmask     '255.255.255.0'
  option  ip6assign   '60'
  list    dns         '8.8.8.8'
  option  gateway     '10.13.1.201'
  option  ipaddr      '10.13.1.200'
  option  ifname      'eth0.1'

config interface 'ovs2'
  option  ifname      'eth0.2'
  option  proto       'none'
  option  force_link  '1'

config interface 'ovs3'
  option  ifname      'eth0.3'
  option  proto       'none'
  option  force_link  '1'

config interface 'ovs4'
  option  ifname      'eth0.4'
  option  proto       'none'
  option  force_link  '1'

config interface 'ovs5'
  option  ifname      'eth0.5'
  option  proto       'none'
  option  force_link  '1'



Default /etc/config/network:
config interface 'loopback'
  option  device      'lo'
  option  proto       'static'
  option  ipaddr      '127.0.0.1'
  option  netmask     '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
  option ula_prefix 'fd3c:bb3e:760f::/48'
  option packet_steering '1'

config device
  option  name        'br-lan'
  option  type        'bridge'
  list    ports       'lan2'
  list    ports       'lan3'
  list    ports       'lan4'
  list    ports       'lan5'

config device
  option  name        'lan2'
  option  macaddr     '48:a9:8a:ec:b1:72'

config device
  option  name        'lan3'
  option  macaddr     '48:a9:8a:ec:b1:72'

config device
  option  name        'lan4'
  option  macaddr     '48:a9:8a:ec:b1:72'

config device
  option  name        'lan5'
  option  macaddr     '48:a9:8a:ec:b1:72'

config interface 'lan'
  option  device      'br-lan'
  option  proto       'static'
  option  ipaddr      '192.168.1.1'
  option  netmask     '255.255.255.0'
  option  ip6assign   '60'

config device
  option  name        'wan'
  option  macaddr     '48:a9:8a:ec:b1:71'

config interface 'wan'
  option  device      'wan'
  option  proto       'dhcp'

config interface 'wan6'
  option  device      'wan'
  option  proto       'dhcpv6'


Why can't you SSH?  Just no response on TCP port 22?  Can you get any IP response (e.g. ICMP, using ping)?  Any TCP response, e.g. ports 443 (HTTPS) or 80 (HTTP)?  Can you use a web interface to just disable SSH altogether?  If so, can you re-enable it?  Or use a web interface to enable Telnet?  Many Mikrotik systems can be altered using a protocol on port 8291 (maybe called the Winbox protocol), used with their Winbox software.  Does that respond?  What, if anything, can you still do with the device?

What were the contents of the old /etc/config/network?

I added the default content on my question

Why is the Mac using Port 1 [WAN]? Is your /etc/config/network config from a prior version of OpenWrt? OpenWrt ~v23 changed the formatting of /etc/config/network, and while I'm unsure what changes were made (besides requiring config device and vlan switches are also different), I do know it will not work with a pasted config from an earlier version of OpenWrt without modification (not from v21, possibly v22 as well). /etc/config/network is also malformed: (1) mgmt interface list dns should be option dns | (2) Is mgmt intentionally missing a broadcast address?

(Cont'd...) @zahntheo Are there any other network issues with connected devices (such as DHCP)? If you have LuCI installed, does Network → Interfaces load or does it error out with the option to regenerate the config? Since I didn't know what changes to the formatting of /etc/config/network were made, I ended up making all customizations I needed via LuCI, then used a text editor to customize the formatting of the config for propagation to my other OpenWrt routers (I heavily format my configs, aligning content similar to the edit I made, as I manage all configs via SSH, not LuCI)
